# What's the difference between a memory leaking closure and its easy workaround?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-leaks

While reading the fabulous docs at [MDN regarding closure leaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) there is shown an example of memory leaking closure along with an surprisingly easy fix.

Can someone better explain how simply combining the two lines (i.e. removing the `el` variable) stops the leak? To my brain the two examples are functionally identical.

```
function addHandler() {
    var el = document.getElementById('el');
    el.onclick = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    };
}
```

> The simplest workaround is not to use the el variable:

```
function addHandler(){
    document.getElementById('el').onclick = function(){
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    };
}
```

Comment: That article also says `Whenever JavaScript executes a function, a 'scope' object is created to hold the local variables created within that function. It is initialised with any variables passed in as function parameters` A "scope _object_"???

Answer (score 1):

The first version retains a reference to the DOM node in the local variable "el"; the second does not. Because of the semantics of closures, that means that code in the bound event handler can access the variable, so the variable remains "live".

Now, because code in the event handler does not actually reference "el", I question whether that would really be a memory leak in a modern JavaScript environment. Since the discussion in that tutorial seems to be about Internet Explorer (and old versions of it at that), the concern over this sort of memory leak is probably still relevant but getting less so.

Comment: Serious question: Did you mean your last word to be `irrelevant`?

Comment: @bits ha ha no, but I should clarify.

Comment: Where is the reference retained? I don't see any leak here. The variable isn't part of the closure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes I agree - the only way it'd be a leak would be if the runtime maintained the closure (and the variable, and hence the reference to the DOM node) blindly without regard to the code actually in the handler function. It's not hard for me to imagine that that's what old runtimes did, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit huh?  Do you agree that if the event handler function *did* reference the "el" variable that there'd be a leak?

Comment: @Pointy: Yes of course. You would then be "closing" over that variable, and in a way that results in a cyclic dependency. But in neither of these examples is there such a scenario.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Right. What I *don't* know (perhaps you do) is whether any JavaScript runtime systems would treat the outer lexical context (where "el" is declared) as being "live" simply because the bound handler function *exists*.  I agree that there's no point to its being kept "live", but making the determination that the handler is "clean" isn't (or might not have been) trivial.

Comment: @Pointy: As far as I know it just comes down to reference counting the actual objects. I see no reason for _any_ implementation to eschew that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well my presumption was that the handler function would be constructed such that it internally retained a reference to the outer-scope activation record itself, not the "el" variable but the object that implicitly exists when the lexical scope is entered. I repeat that I am not a JavaScript runtime system implementor, or the implementor/maintainer of anything similar. Perhaps that's a good thing :)

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah I can't say for sure either. I'd be surprised though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you're actually enclosing any variables here. There is no memory leak and the two snippets *are* the same.

Comment: @skube: Yes, I suppose I am. See my comment under the question for further evidence that this may not be any sort of a stretch. Carl makes a good point in his answer, though. I'm not 100% sure of the facts here.

Answer (score 0):

To further clarify @Pointy's answer: the 'el' var keeps the 'el' DOM element alive because it references it directly.  The 'el' DOM element's onClick event is set to a closure that *might* reference the 'el' var.  That the code shown doesn't ref it explicitly is no guarantee here, since you could use an eval() with a dynamically build string as well to ref the 'el' var - there's no way to tell for the browser.  So the onClick of the 'el' DOM element in turn keeps the 'el' var alive.  This results in a circular reference between JavaScript and the DOM, which the browser cannot break - hence a memory leak.

Since you do want to set an onClick handler for the DOM element, the solution is to break the circle by not having the 'el' var in the closure's scope.